Undefined Variable $tenant in Laravel
I have an undefined variable $tenant error message. I want my code to return data from the companies associated with the user.
View
<ul>
    @foreach ($tenant as $tenantx)
        <li>{{ $tenantx->nome }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>

Controller
public function index()
{
    $userId =  auth()->id();
    $tenants['tenant'] = Tenant::where('user_id', $userId)->get();

    return view('dashboard', ['tenant' => $tenants['tenant']]);
}


In controller:
 public function index()
    {
        $userId =  auth()->id();
        $data['tenants'] = Tenant::where('user_id', $userId)->get();
        return view('dashboard', $data);
    }

In view:
    <ul>
     @foreach ($tenants as $tenantx)
          <li>{{ $tenantx->nome }}</li>
      @endforeach
   </ul>

Hope it's work now.
